# Slow psql import

Tags: postgresql, psql, pg-dump

I have a set of backups from my databases and they are in `sql` format. I am using following command to import them

```
Restore: $ psql -U {user-name} -d {desintation_db} -f {dumpfilename.sql}
```

It works well but I noticed that if prints out logs and it seems it is importing them row by row, For a 200Mb database it takes long time to import and I have several databases which they are around 20GB. Is there any faster way to import them? This method seems not to practical at all.

Comment: `pg_dump` does not generate single row inserts, so restoring it also doesn't import it "row by row". But it does import one table after the other. If you think the log output slows down the process, you can disable it using the `--quiet` option for psql

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the --inserts option to pg_dump forces it to use a `insert into t(a,b,c) values(x,y,z); [repeatedly]` format , which can be very bulky. (luckily, no sane person would use it routinely)

Answer (score 2):

You should use the custom format (`-F c`) or the directory format (`-F d`) to dump your data. Then you can parallelize restore with the `-j` option of `pg_restore`.

This parallelizes the `COPY` statements that load the data and the `CREATE INDEX` statements. if your database consist of a single large table, that won't help you, but otherwise you should see a performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

They are imported in whatever fashion was encoded in the sql file. That is generally going to be with COPY, but you could have done it with individual INSERTs if that is what you told pg_dump to do.